# Error E5113 while installing dashboard with vim Plug

Tags: neovim, plugin-vim-plug, plugin-dashboard

I'm new to vim and nvim and right now I'm trying to set everything up. I'm using vimplug to install Plugins. While installing Dashboard I got the following error message:

```
Error detected while processing /home/name/.local/share/nvim/plugged/dashboard-nvim/plugin/dashboard.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: ...l/share/nvim/plugged/dashboard-nvim/plugin/dashboard.lua:9: attempt to call field 'nvim_create_augroup' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        ...l/share/nvim/plugged/dashboard-nvim/plugin/dashboard.lua:9: in main chunk
```

In my init.vim file regarding Dashboard right now I only have

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'https://github.com/nvimdev/dashboard-nvim'
call plug#end()
```

Now the obvious question is how to fix this.

Comment: I would report this to the plugin maintainers; they’re likely to know the answer. (I suspect a version issue: find out when that neovim function was introduced or if it’s been deprecated/removed.)

Comment: Most likely not the cause of your error but the `https://github.com` part can be omitted. You can shorten the line to `Plug 'nvimdev/dashboard-nvim`. Another piece of unsolicited advice: don't put more on your plate than you can eat. You're new to Vim, start without plugins and only install them once you're comfortable with the editor.